# while and for loop in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

1)

```
 i = 0;

 while(i < N){

   j = i+1;

   while(j < N && p[i].first == p[j].first && p[j].second - p[i].second < K) j++;

     i = j; res++;

             }
```

2)

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){

   j = i+1;

   while(j < N && p[i].first == p[j].first && p[j].second - p[i].second < K) j++;

     i = j; res++;
                 }
```

the first code and the second code differs only due to while loop in 1) and for loop in 
2). But According to me the outputs due to both of them should be same but it differs.
Both the above codes are only a part of the total code. But I should tell you the output  due to 1) is 2 whereas due to 2) is 3.

I don't why the answer is different because everything happening is same.

Comment: after 2) it is for(i=0;i<N;i++).

Comment: See this - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context

Comment: @VladLazarenko Oh come on, it won't help him/her in any way.

Comment: @DesmondHume: proper English helps a lot.

Answer (score 8):

The for loop increments i twice.  Once in the for loop definition itself (`i++`) and then indirectly via `j`.

The while loop only does the indirect increment via `j`. So the two examples are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think to make equals the loops you should omit the increment in for:

```
for(i=0; i<N; ){
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, the variable i is incremented twice in your code:
First time at

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
```

and second time at

`j = i+1` followed by `i = j`